# DocuSign API - GET Audit Events as PDF

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to get a PDF of the Envelope History that you can view from the DocuSign website when viewing the Envelope details and clicking on the More menu and selecting History:

[image]

which has the list of Activities that can be easily printed or saved as a PDF?

It looks like the [listAuditEvents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/listauditevents/) API endpoint returns the corresponding data but I was hoping to get this as PDF like on the History page as well. Is this one of the Documents that can be downloaded for an Envelope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a PDF of the Envelope History that you can view from the DocuSign website when viewing the Envelope details and clicking on the More menu and selecting History

No. But you just need to use the API call you noted, then create a PDF from the response data using one of the many PDF libraries available.